# String analysis and classification

Tags: java, string, analysis

I am developing a financial manager in my freetime with Java and Swing GUI. When the user adds a new entry, he is prompted to fill in: Moneyamount, Date, Comment and Section (e.g. Car, Salary, Computer, Food,...)

The sections are created "on the fly". When the user enters a new section, it will be added to the section-jcombobox for further selection. The other point is, that the comments could be in different languages. So the list of hard coded words and synonyms would be enormous.

So, my question is, is it possible to analyse the comment (e.g. "Fuel", "Car service", "Lunch at **") and preselect a fitting Section.
My first thought was, do it with a neural network and learn from the input, if the user selects another section.

But my problem is, I don´t know how to start at all. I tried "encog" with Eclipse and did some tutorials (XOR,...). But all of them are only using doubles as in/output.

Anyone could give me a hint how to start or any other possible solution for this?

[Here](http://www.multiupload.com/ELP0BKCHY8) is a runable JAR (current development state, requires Java7) and the [Sourceforge Page](http://sourceforge.net/p/jammdevel/home/Home/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about neural networks. This is a highly technical and specialized field of artificial intelligence, which is probably not suitable for your problem, and requires a solid expertise. Besides, there is a lot of simpler and better solutions for your problem.

First obvious solution, build a list of words and synonyms for all your sections and parse for these synonyms. You can then collect comments online for synonyms analysis, or use parse comments/sections provided by your users to statistically detect relations between words, etc...

There is an infinite number of possible solutions, ranging from the simplest to the most overkill. Now you need to define if this feature of your system is critical (prefilling? probably not, then)... and what any development effort will bring you. One hour of work could bring you a 80% satisfying feature, while aiming for 90% would cost one week of work. Is it really worth it?

Go for the simplest solution and tackle the real challenge of any dev project: delivering. Once your app is delivered, then you can always go back and improve as needed.

Comment: I think the word list would be too large, due to the dynamical section creation and possible languages. For a better understanding there are links in the first post. (JAR+Source)

Comment: With our modern machines, I would say there's no such thing as a word list that is too large... Even a dictionary of synonyms can easily fit into memory.

Comment: Would it be possible to store all used words in comments except blocked words (in, and, the,...) in a DB and then assign the selected section to it and when the user adds a comment, go throught (the BIG DB) and select the section according to the entries for the words? I think the performance would be quite low, due to the large ammount of data.

Comment: A good text-searching algorithm is O(log n) or less, the amount of data is almost irrelevant, the performance can be extremely good. Did you notice that Google can predict what you're typing, display search result in real time, return results in a few milliseconds? All these algorithms are available and easy to use. So yes, what you describe is possible, easy and really fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myString =  new String(paramInput);

if(myString.contains("FUEL")){
//do the fuel functionality
}
```

Comment: See comment at GP Singh´s answer

Answer (score 0):

In a simple app, if you will be having only **some specific sections** in your application then you can get string from comments and check it if it contains some **keywords** and then according to it change the value of Section.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. But the problem is, that the sections are created "on the fly". When the user enters a new section, it will be added to the section-jcombobox for further selection. So, its not that easy :( The other thing is, that the comments could be in different languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of categories, I would use something like Apache Lucene where you could index all the categories with their name's and potential keywords/phrases that might appear in a users description. Then you could simply run the description through Lucene and use the top matched category as a "best guess".

P.S. Neural Network inputs and outputs will always be doubles or floats with a value between 0 and 1. As for how to implement String matching I wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: See comment at GP Singh´s answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that following will do:

- hard word statistics
- maybe a stemming class (English/Spanish) which reduce a word like "lunches" to "lunch".
- a list of most frequent non-words (the, at, a, for, ...)

The best fit is a linear problem, so theoretical fit for a neural net, but why not take immediately the numerical best fit.

Answer (score 0):

A machine learning algorithm such as an Artificial Neural Network doesn't seem like the best solution here. ANNs can be used for multi-class classification (i.e. 'to which of the provided pre-trained classes does the input represent?' not just 'does the input represent an X?') which fits your use case. The problem is that they are supervised learning methods and as such you need to provide a list of pairs of keywords and classes (Sections) that spans every possible input that your users will provide. This is impossible and in practice ANNs are re-trained when more data is available to produce better results and create a more accurate decision boundary / representation of the function that maps the inputs to outputs. This also assumes that you know all possible classes before you start and each of those classes has training input values that you provide.

The issue is that the input to your ANN (a list of characters or a numerical hash of the string) provides no context by which to classify. There's no higher level information provided  that describes the word's meaning. This means that a different word that hashes to a numerically close value can be misclassified if there was insufficient training data.

(As maclema said, the output from an ANN will always be floats with each value representing proximity to a class - or a class with a level of uncertainty.)

A better solution would be to employ some kind of word-relation or synonym graph. A [Bag of words model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words_model) might be useful here.

Edit: In light of your comment that you don't know the Sections before hand,
an easy solution to program would be to provide a list of keywords in a file that gets updated as people use the program. Simply storing a mapping of provided comments -> Sections, which you will already have in your database, would allow you to filter out non-keywords (and, or, the, ...). One option is to then  find a list of each Section that the typed keywords belong to and suggest multiple Sections and let the user pick one. The feedback that you get from user selections would enable improvements of suggestions in the future. Another would be to calculate a [Bayesian probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability) - the probability that this word belongs to Section X given the previous stored mappings - for all keywords and Sections and either take the modal Section or normalise over each unique keyword and take the mean. Calculations of probabilities will need to be updated as you gather more information ofcourse, perhaps this could be done with every new addition in a background thread.